# Access a file inside gitlab -nested folder

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am able to access the .config file.

```
https://gitlab.agile.nat.bt.com/api/v4/projects/12835/repository/files/Nuget.config/raw?ref=master&private_token=ixUu9xMdnvhS5R-qYSj1
```

As per below , it has nuget.config file. which I am able to access it. But I am interested to fetch file inside EnvironmentFiles. Inside EnvironmentFiles folder it has a abc.xml file.I want to read the xml file.

```
[
 {
    "id": "de9688b5f473ce27cb089f0d34b5a06a81847301",
    "name": "**EnvironmentFiles**",
    "type": "tree",
    "path": "EnvironmentFiles",
    "mode": "040000"
  },
  {
    "id": "7b7031bcbedb161f54f59aa8faf2689d298ad6ca",
    "name": "**Nuget.config**",
    "type": "blob",
    "path": "Nuget.config",
    "mode": "100644"
  }
]
```

I am able to see the xml file by running the below url. But I am not able to fetch the xml file.

```
https://gitlab.agile.nat.bt.com/api/v4/projects/12835/repository/tree?path=EnvironmentFiles&private_token=ixUu9xMdnvhS5R-qYSj1
```

How shall I access the xml file

Comment: https://gitlab.agile.nat.bt.com/api/v4/projects/12835/repository/files/EnvironmentFiles/abc.xml/raw?ref=master&private_token=ixUu9xMdnvhS5R-qYSj1

this doesnot work

Comment: The *Git* answer is "clone the repository, then access the file from the clone". You presumably don't want this answer, so don't use the [tag:git] tag.